# Why is Chrome coloring my cookie red when I set it from the inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

If I open the inspector for a page, go to the Application tab, scroll down to Cookies in the left-hand list, expand it, and click my domain, I get a list of cookies set on the domain. I can add new entries to the list and edit existing ones, setting and updating cookies stored for that domain.

After upgrading to Chrome 73 if I try and set a cookie the browser colors the text red and does not set or save the cookie. How do I continue setting cookies in Chrome 73?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Chrome 73 and later cookies must have a value for the Expires/Max-Age column or they will not be set. Double-click that field and enter 2100 to set a Expires time of 2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z for your cookie.

Comment: What value would you put to create a session cookie?

Comment: Type in the literal string `Session` into the Expires/Max-Age column. The box will say N/A but it'll save the cookie instead of coloring the row red.

Answer (score 30):

Solved it by

1. search in chrome settings for flags by entering in the url field `chrome://flags`
2. search `Partitioned cookies` and set it to `enable`
3. Restart chrome (might need to refresh the page after the restart and it works like before did)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the new version of Chrome

Comment: What is this actually doing?

Comment: Chrome bug (per @CoperNick) workaround is to set the cookie in the console. 

`document.cookie = "mycookie=myvalue";`

Comment: @Tallboy it enables usage of Partitioned cookies :D More on partitioned cookies https://chromestatus.com/feature/5179189105786880