# Issue while adding a cookie in Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Screenshot of trying to add a cookie]

I am getting this issue while adding a cookie in Chrome dev tools (it gets highlighted in red), so I am not able to add any cookies. I even tried to reset the Chrome browser, but it's not working.

Comment: Looks like you need to specify "Expires / Max-Age" of cookies in the list.
Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364173/why-is-chrome-coloring-my-cookie-red-when-i-set-it-from-the-inspector)

Answer (score 14):

If you update your chrome or restart your laptop recently(10-Feb-2022), you cannot add cookies manually in chrome now. The reason is the newest update of Chome disable the `SameSite by default cookies` setting.

the solution is:

1. open this url in chrome: `chrome://flags`
2. search Partitioned cookies, and enable it

Comment: Tried this approach but it didn't solve it for me

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!

Comment: Did not work for me right away after the chrome browser restart, had to refresh the site one more time before actually being able to add the cookie manually. #Macos